# Powershell 'Move-Item' doesn't make directory if it doesn't exist

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script which does a lot of things and one of them is moving files:

```
$from = $path + '\' + $_.substring(8)
$to   = $quarantaine + '\' + $_.substring(8)

Move-Item $from $to
```

But it happens the directory structure isn't already present in the `$to` path. So I would like Powershell to create it with this commando. I've tried `Move-Item -Force $from $to`, but that didn't help out.

What can I do to make sure Powershell creates the needed directories in order to get things working?
I hope I make myself clear, if not, please ask!

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695504/powershell-2-copy-item-which-creates-a-folder-if-doesnt-exist

Comment: That's what I tried already, with no luck. As mentioned in my question

Comment: Could do a copy and delete.

Answer (score 19):

You could create it yourself:

```
$from = Join-Path $path $_.substring(8)
$to = Join-Path $quarantaine $_.substring(8)

if(!(Test-Path $to))
{
    New-Item -Path $to -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}

Move-Item $from $to
```

Comment: `-PathType Container` is not a parameter for `New-Item`. Remove this and it works as expected.

Comment: Is there no easier solution nowadays - like an parameter or so

Answer (score 6):

You could use the system.io.directory .NET class to check for destination directory and create if it doesn't exist.
Here is an example using your variables:-

```
if (!([system.io.directory]::Exists($quarantine))){
   [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory($quarantine)
}
Copy-File $from $to
```

Comment: Why would you use this over the simpler and more common `Test-Path`/`New-Item`?

Comment: @NelsonRothermel At the time of writing I was new to powershell, unaware of them and the answer I gave was how I would do this at the time - this was 4 years ago. These days I would indeed use test-path/new-item.

Comment: @NelsonRothermel it's actually something I find pretty nice about powershell though - if you come into it with a .NET background, a lot of what you are used to is portable and reusable in powershell with ease. And if there's not a cmdlet that does what you need, but there's a .NET class that does, problem solved!

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I was just wondering if there was something I didn't know. I do like how you can fall back on full .NET as needed or even write your own.

Comment: Actually you don't need `Exists($quarantine)` with `CreateDirectory` because it does it internally anyways. Even better, if you have access to `\\server\share\my\path` directory but not `\\server\share\my` directory `Exists(@"\\server\share\my\path\subfolder")` will fail but `CreateDirectory(@"\\server\share\my\path\subfolder")` won't.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a utility function like this:

```
Function Move-Item-Parent([string]$path, [string]$destination) {
    New-Item $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
    Move-Item $path $destination
}
```

Then invoke it like this:

```
Move-Item-Parent $from $to
```