# Powershell Copy-Item -Destination

Tags: powershell, copy-item

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\$SiteMachineName\c$\ProgramData\Scripts\log -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-40)} |
    select * |
    Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Copy-Item -Destination C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\PS
```

This is the script I'm trying to run, It grabs all the files older then 40 days from the script folder on a remote machine. This part works. The issue is that if I don't have a folder on my desktop named PS, it just creates a file named PS instead of copying all the files to that folder location.

I would like it to create that folder location if it does not exist.

This is not a duplicate adding the -force -Recurse gives the error

Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path

adding the New-Item to the Destination flag resolved the issue.

Comment: *I would like it to create that folder location if it does not exist.* Umm... what's stopping you from doing just that?

Comment: What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\<PC>\c$\ProgramData\Scripts\log\log.log Destination: C:\Users\scotry\Desktop\PS".  Copies the file to a file on my desktop instead of going into a folder named PS

Comment: Just create the folder if it doesn't exist. *Before* you start copying stuff to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `Copy-Item`'s `Destination` flag with a `New-Item -force` directive:

```
copy-item -Destination (new-item -type directory -force ("C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\PS")) -force
```

[Source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461932/866021)

Comment: This worked slick, thank you from other peoples comments I could of also if ( !(test-path $dest\Script)){
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dest\Script -force
            }