# Powershell - Compress files based on the contents of another zip file

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, compression, azure-pipelines, compress-archive

I have a zip file that has to be extracted to a destination folder. Before I extract I want to backup **ONLY** the root files and the sub directories that will be replaces by extracting the zip file.

Can I write up a script that will be find out the sub directories within the .zip and backup those from the destination folder (if they are available)?

And I will be using this script in Azure DevOps.

Comment: So do want to check all the zip content and backup it before?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to discover the zip file content, check if it exists in the destination folder, if yes - do a backup. for example:

```
$ZipFilePath = "C:\Users\sabramczyk\Documents\Scrum.zip"
$DestinationFolder = "c:\test"

Add-Type -assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
    
if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($ZipFilePath)) {
    throw "Zip file ""$ZipFilePath"" not found."
}

$ZipContent = ([System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($ZipFilePath)).Entries.FullName
foreach($zipContent in $ZipContent)
{
    if(Test-Path $DestinationFolder+"/"+$zipContent)
    {
        # Do backup
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect :) Thanks... I tried to use copy-item to backup these files into a separate folder, and I was unable to preserve the directory structure.

Copy-Item -Path $FullFilePath -Destination $(ReleaseClientWorkFolder)\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)\PreReleaseCopies\CISIWeb2\$zipContent

Comment: What is `$FullFilePath`? and I don't understand completely the issue...

Comment: $FullFilePath is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb2\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll 

For an example so when I copy this to lets says D:\Backup\MyWeb2, the copied file is always in the root, I want the file to maintain the same directory structure. So I want the file to be copied to D:\Backup\MyWeb2\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

Comment: try to append the structure to the backup folder path or copy only the folders (with files) and not individual files

Comment: The folder (Inetpub) has a lot more content (both folders and files) that I dont really need. That's my issue here.

Comment: Solved it by doing a new-item before copy-item (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027762/powershell-copy-item-destination)

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it will be to extract file from your zip to some temporary folder (on Azure DevOps it could be folder behind this variable `Agent.TempDirectory`). Then you can copy files you want to backup to another location like `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/backup` and pack this folder and put in `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` if you want to publish them. After this you can extract zip again to your destinations as you already have your backup.

You may find this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) useful if you want to more about above mentioned folders.

Comment: I can do that, However the destination folder has heaps of directories and contents. I don't want to backup all the contents.

Comment: @Muhammedh Yes, this is why I recommend you to extract it to clean folder like  `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/MyCleanFolder` and get files only those you need to backup. And at the end extract to you destination folder. But clean folder to create backup is not your destination folder.

Comment: @krzysztof-medej How will I know which files to backup? I want to get the list of folders that I will be replacing.

Comment: Ok. I see, so you don't know what is in destination folder. For that part please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526441/comparing-folders-and-content-with-powershell